# Solr - combine stats component with range facet on DateRangField

Tags: solr, facet

I want to count the number of distinct values in a long-field for every gap of a range facet, while the facet field is a DateRangeField.

I am able to come up with valid query using the JSON facet API:

```
json.facet={ 
  RangeCounts:{
    type: range,
    field: MyDateRange,
    start:2019-01-01T00:00:00Z,
    end:NOW/DAY,
    gap:+1DAY,
    facet:{
        CountDistinct:"hll(ItemId)"  *or unqiue(ItemId)
    }   
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the JSON facet API does not allow facet on DateRangeFields. This seems to be a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10567), so I'm trying to make it work by using simple facets.

To give you an idea what I am looking for, here is one of my pathetic attempts to come up with a query:

```
stats=true
stats.field={!tag=s1 cardinality=true}ItemId  *or countDistinct=true
facet=true
facet.range={!stats=s1}MyDaterange
facet.range.start=2019-01-01T00:00:00Z,
facet.range.end=NOW/DAY
facet.range.gap=+1DAY
```

However, this is obviously only giving me the global countDistinct and not the pivoted results. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at [Pivot faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Pivot_DecisionTree_Faceting). It can be combined with stats,and it should work. Here is the [doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-CombiningStatsComponentWithPivots)

Comment: Thanks. Pivot faceting was actually the first thing I looked at but I don't see how I can apply this to get stats inside a range facet. Any idea?

Comment: did you see the combination with stats part?

Comment: Yes. But that only combines stats with a regular facet. facet.pivot={!stats=s1}MyDaterange will not give me a range facet.